# fancybox in ipad application

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am developing an app in HTML5 for Ipad.

I added the metatag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

But the Fancybox not work because this opened in a self window (black window).

The fancybox code is:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
var $js = jQuery;

$js(document).ready(function() {

    $js(".modalwin").fancybox({
        width: 980,
        height: 600,
        maxWidth: 980,
        maxHeight: 600,
        fitToView: false,
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'fade',
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        type: 'iframe',
        margin: 0,
        padding: 5,
        openSpeed: 'fast',
        closeSpeed: 'fast',
        scrolling: 'no',
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)'
                }
            }
        },
        beforeShow: function() {
            $js(".fancybox-skin").css("backgroundColor", "#D84B04");
        }
    })
});
```

And to prevent to open links in a blank page outside app I used:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
var $jx = jQuery;

$jx(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    location.href = $jx(event.target).attr("href");
});​
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the second script `$jx(document).on("click"`? have you tried without it? ... got a link?

Answer (score 0):

I founded the answer:

```
    jQuery.noConflict ();
    var $jx = jQuery;

    $jx(document).delegate("a:not(.modalwin)", "click", function(event){
    window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: in that case `$jx(document).on("click","a:not(.modalwin)", ...` would do a better job (requires jQuery 1.7+ though)